# Changing select value using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a form with three dropdown combos. One of them shows a city name;

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
        <label for="name">Ciudad</label>
 <select class="form-control" id="ciudad_combo">
 <option>Selecciona Ciudad</option>
 </select>
  </div>
```

I am populating it using AJAX and PHP/MySQL.

But I also need to set a value if another condition is met.

I am trying to do it as follows:

```
if(components[component].types[0]=="locality"){
                var ciudad=components[component].long_name;

                $("#ciudad_combo").val("San Francisco");
            }
```

But the output changes from the initial value "Selecciona Ciudad" to nothing, the option appears to be empty.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `San Francisco` is not an option in that list so it's can't be selected. Did you mean to add an option then select it?

Comment: @Popnoodles, understood, but if I need to put San Francisco as option, what should be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the option, and set is as selected

`$('<option>').text('San Francisco').appendTo('#ciudad_combo').prop('selected', true);`

https://jsfiddle.net/kpfy6nbr/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#ciudad_combo')
    .append('<option value="SF" selected="selected">San Francisco</option>')
```

Comment: cool.. can we close this thread? you can mark this or the Answer above.. thanks. @mvasco

Comment: I have to wait 4 minutes